# WFP - odd behaviour when opening new tab

Tags: wpf

The user can select from a DataGrid either by double clicking on the row, or selecting the row and clicking a button.

Using the first method the new page is initialised but the loaded event is not fired.

Using the second method the new page is initialised, the old one fires the unloaded event and the new one fires the loaded event and the new tab opens.

As both the click and doubleclick events are firing the same sub I can't figure out why one works and the other doesn't - when not in debug the new tab is formed using the first method and when clicked the loaded event is then fired, but this doesn't show in debug.

```
Private Sub Reports_BalanceSheets_EditRecord(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Try
        NewRecord = False
        Dim DGV As CustomControl.DGVx = Reports_BalanceSheets_Grid.FindName("Reports_BalanceSheets_DGV")
        If DGV.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
            Dim row As System.Data.DataRowView = DGV.SelectedItems(0)
            FormID = row("ID")
            Dim vName As String = row("Name")
            Dim vTab As CustomControl.STC_Tabx = Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("Reports_BalanceSheetTab")
            Dim TabControl As CustomControl.STCx = Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("AccountingReports_TabControl")
            Dim vImageSource As String = ReturnImageAsString("Profit_Loss.png", 16)
            If vTab Is Nothing Then
                Dim ReportsBalanceSheetFrame As New Frame

                Dim Tab As New CustomControl.STC_Tabx
                With Tab
                    .Name = "Reports_BalanceSheetTab"
                    .Header = " Edit " & vName & " "
                    .CloseButtonVisibility = DevComponents.WpfEditors.eTabCloseButtonVisibility.Visible
                    .TabToolTip = "Edit " & vName
                    .ImageSource = vImageSource
                    .Content = ReportsBalanceSheetFrame
                End With
                AddHandler Tab.Closing, AddressOf TabControl_TabClosing
                Dim vGrid As Grid = Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("MainGrid_Website")
                RegisterControl(vGrid, Tab, Tab.Name.ToString)
                TabControl.Items.Add(Tab)


                Dim BalanceSheet As New Reports_BalanceSheet_Page
                ReportsBalanceSheetFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(BalanceSheet)
                TabControl.SelectedItem = Tab

            Else
                vTab.Close()
                Dim ReportsBalanceSheetFrame As New Frame
                Dim Tab As New CustomControl.STC_Tabx
                With Tab
                    .Name = "Reports_BalanceSheetTab"
                    .Header = " Edit " & vName & " "
                    .CloseButtonVisibility = DevComponents.WpfEditors.eTabCloseButtonVisibility.Visible
                    .TabToolTip = "Edit " & vName
                    .ImageSource = vImageSource
                    .Content = ReportsBalanceSheetFrame
                End With
                AddHandler Tab.Closing, AddressOf TabControl_TabClosing
                Dim vGrid As Grid = Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("MainGrid_Website")
                RegisterControl(vGrid, Tab, Tab.Name.ToString)
                TabControl.Items.Add(Tab)

                Dim BalanceSheet As New Reports_BalanceSheet_Page
                ReportsBalanceSheetFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(BalanceSheet)
                TabControl.SelectedItem = Tab

            End If
        ElseIf DGV.SelectedItems.Count > 1 Then
            AppBoxValidation("You can only select one item at a time to edit!")
        Else
            AppBoxValidation("You must select an item to edit!")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't update with the answer for another 8 hours, but e.handled sorted it out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding e.Handled resolved the issue